# How to read JSON's specific field and calculate it and display

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I want to read my JSON and calculate score and display total 
This is not working, any suggestion for modification of code.

**HTML**

```
<div> <p id="newme"> </p> </div>
```

**JS**

```
    var points = {"marks" : [
                                {"Subject" : csharp, "Score" : 5},
                                {"Subject" : csharp, "Score" : 7},
                                {"Subject" : Java, "Score" : 6},
                                {"Subject" : cpp, "Score" : 9 },
                                {"Subject" : Java, "Score" : 10},
                                {"Subject" : Java, "Score" : 4}
                            ]
                };
points = JSON.stringify(points);
var Java = "Java";
for (var i=0;i<points.marks.length;i++){
if(points.marks[i].Subject==Java){
    var totJava = totJava + points.marks[i].Score;
}
}
document.getElementById("newme").innerHTML= totJava;
```

[I have tired this on Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XQymX/)

Answer (score 1):

You can't have like this

```
"Subject" : csharp,  //ERROR
```

Better enclose those values with double quotes `"csharp"`

```
var points = {
    "marks": [{
        "Subject": "csharp",
            "Score": 5
    }, {
        "Subject": "csharp",
            "Score": 7
    }, {
        "Subject": "Java",
            "Score": 6
    }, {
        "Subject": "cpp",
            "Score": 9
    }, {
        "Subject": "Java",
            "Score": 10
    }, {
        "Subject": "Java",
            "Score": 4
    }]
};

//points = JSON.stringify(points);  //NO NEED TO PARSE THIS
var Java = "Java";
var totJava = 0; // declare globally with default 0 as value
for (var i = 0; i < points.marks.length; i++) {

    if (points.marks[i].Subject == Java) {
        totJava = totJava + points.marks[i].Score;
    }
}
document.getElementById("newme").innerHTML = totJava;
```

Comment: i am filling this object dynamically
points.marks.push({
   "Subject" : subj,
   "Score" : sliderAmount
  });

Comment: how to provide single/double quotes from here?

Comment: @Phoenix Does `subj` is a variable that contains the `string value`?

Comment: var subj = document.getElementById("subjTitle").innerHTML;

Comment: @Phoenix `innerHTML` always returns `string` value so you no need to worry about conversion.  Since your question does not show the dynamic  generated value I wrote this answer.

Comment: yes because in console i am getting "Subject": "Java",
this only

Comment: @Phoenix you got it. FYI: [jsonlint](http://jsonlint.com/) is nice online tool to check your json

Comment: yes Praveen  jsfiddle.net/XQymX/6? is working fine but its not in my code i will try something else too, in mean time if you have any suggestion plz let me knw

Comment: what is no wrap-in <body> ??

Comment: @Phoenix Adding your script within your body like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/XQymX/7/) this has quite good performance too.  In your case, the method first before the DOM get loaded and therefore you got error.

Comment: Is it happening because .innerHTML.
I am taking that number by this. 
In console i am getting **Score: "3"**.
"3" is it valid??

Comment: @Phoenix no its not.  better parse it to a number like `           totJava = totJava + (+points.marks[i].Score);`  Also check dev console (press f12) or inspect element and see console for any error.  So you can fix your bugs by yourself which makes you happy :)

Answer (score 1):

First of All its not a valid JSon its simple javascript object 
Second you should have provide a default total

See the [solution here](http://jsfiddle.net/vinodlouis/468YR/)

```
var Java = "Java";
var totJava = 0;
for (var i=0;i<points.marks.length;i++){
   if(points.marks[i].Subject==Java){
     totJava += parseInt(points.marks[i].Score,10);
   }
}
document.getElementById("newme").innerHTML= totJava;
```

Comment: its not working again with little modification[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XQymX/4/)

Comment: you cannot have  "Subject": csharp, it should be "Subject": "csharp" as csharp is a string not a varible

Comment: its not working again with little modification[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XQymX/5/)

Comment: try this http://jsfiddle.net/vinodlouis/NKJFk/ put it in nowrap body in left side of fiddle option and write java as "java inside calulation function"

Answer (score 1):

Couple of points were wrong here,check updated fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/XQymX/

the json object would be like this

```
var points = {"marks" : [{
                     "Subject" : "csharp",
                     "Score" : 5
                    },{
                     "Subject" : "csharp",
                     "Score" : 7
                    },{
                     "Subject" : "Java",
                     "Score" : 6
                    },{
                     "Subject" : "cpp",
                     "Score" : 9
                    },{
                     "Subject" : "Java",
                     "Score" : 10
                    },{
                     "Subject" : "Java",
                     "Score" : 4
                    }
                  ]
    };
```

and there is no need to do this `points = JSON.stringify(points);`